# Featured image not displaying in WordPress post

Tags: wordpress

I am using a free WordPress theme. I am able to add a featured image to a post but the image is not displayed.

I have checked `functions.php` and it contains the following code:

```
/* Enable support for Post Thumbnails on posts and pages */
    add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
```

Any ideas what else to check either in the source code or in the WordPress settings?

Comment: Is it not displayed in the backend or not rendering for your visitors?  If it's for your visitors, check the browser console for an potential errors that might be preventing it from loading.

Comment: not rendering for visitors. It is solved now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );` is fine, what it does is, it provides you an option to add the featured image.

But in order to display the image on frontend, you need to call the function that shows the image.

Find your frontend fine, it may be index.php or single.php or any custom file your theme is using.

Find the loop and put the following code,

```
if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
    the_post_thumbnail();
}
```

**It must be inside loop**

For more information check following links,

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_post_thumbnail/

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/

Hope it helps:)

Comment: this worked, thank you so much! I added the code you suggested in single.php. I voted up your answer, it was recorded, but it won't be displayed as I haven't built the reputation yet.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your function.php file.

add_theme_support('post-thumbnails', array(
'post',
'page',
'custom-post-type-name',
));